# How to configure aws sso for terraform?

Tags: terraform-provider-aws, aws-sso

I have been using aws as cloud service and terraform as IaC. It's very annoying to copy paste the credentials frequently. Is there any solution available for that or any work around other to use aws sso?

Comment: Did you follow e.g. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-sso.html to get credentials in your CLI?

Comment: @luk2302 I have not tried. But would that help the issue ? I mean would the terraform will pick the aws sso credential if or unless it supports some similar feature ?

Comment: You should execute the sso login in a shell window and then in the same window run the terraform command which should then use the same credentials.

Answer (score 7):

#### Premise

It was my understanding that there is a current issue between AWS SSO (authentication v2) and terraform; that only V1 authentication (access key and secret key) is reliably accepted.

For example, [this open PR](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/pull/29017) or [this issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/26995) or [this ongoing referenced merge](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/pull/3905)

---

#### Work Around

There are a couple of projects that circumvent this issue by generating V1 creds from AWS SSO.

The one I use is a PyPi library called [yawsso](https://pypi.org/project/yawsso/).

Try this:

```
pip3 install yawsso

yawsso login # this will authenticate - you no longer need to run 'aws sso login'
```

#### Note

Just make sure you use the right profile with `export AWS_PROFILE=foo` where "foo" would be in `~/.aws/config` as `[profile foo]`

#### Bonus

`yawsso` will log you in on all profiles listed in the AWS config file, so you don't need to log in one-by-one into all profiles required at work

Comment: according to https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/28872#issuecomment-972029772, the error was resolved as of terraform v1.06.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that this is possible without external plugins now, see here:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs#shared-configuration-and-credentials-files

Example:

```
provider "aws" {
  profile = "customprofile"
}
```